Change text alignment of TButton using Style
I use a style file to customize my firemonkey application.
I can't change the text alignment of TButton. The text is always center.
Step to reproduce:

Add a TButton
Right click > Change default style
change TButtonStyleTextObject.TextSettings.HorzAlign to Leading

Any idea ?

The TButton control has a property StyledSettings.Other (False by default) that you need to turn to True for your setting to have effect. Alternatively, to change horizontal align without styles, you can set the TButton property TextSettings.HorzAlign to Leading.
